# Why can I ping IPs that are at two different locations?

Tags: networking

So I was wondering why I can ping IPs that are at two different locations. For example, IP A is 172.19.128.7. IP B is 172.19.64.4. They both have different router IP addresses and are each at different locations. If i'm IP B, I can ping and communicate with IP A. This is the LAN Network I am on. I can even ping the WAN network from the LAN network. How is this possible?

Comment: Apparently you have invalid assumptions about what PING is/does. Off-topic here, though.

Comment: Read about few things. 1.Class B Private IP Address , 2.What is Ping , 3.What is subnet and subnet mask, 4.What is difference between network and hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, well your gateway is doing the routing, you didn't specify mask subnet but assuming they're on different networks it's the gateway router's job to allow communication between both networks.

Comment: The LAN(S) have a subnet of 255.255.240.0 and the WAN(S) with a subnet of 255.255.255.0.